# Google earth not showing correct polygon orientation

Tags: 3d, kml, google-earth, kmz

I created a sample kml, in which there are two polygons with same orientation. But in google earth, one is darker than the other one, it shows wrong orientation.

Here is a sample kml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
<name>KmlFile</name>
<Placemark>
<name>Shell Polygons</name>
<MultiGeometry>
<Polygon>
<altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
<outerBoundaryIs>
<LinearRing>
<coordinates>
-1.46794286722133,53.38399869052405,0.9 -1.46794286722724,53.38399869050928,6.720900000000001 -1.46802203110511,53.38399869049681,3 -1.46794286722133,53.38399869052405,0.9
</coordinates>
</LinearRing>
</outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
<Polygon>
<altitudeMode>relativeToGround</altitudeMode>
<outerBoundaryIs>
<LinearRing>
<coordinates>
-1.46802203110511,53.38399869049681,3 -1.46794286722724,53.38399869050928,6.720900000000001 -1.46802203106645,53.38399869048823,6.392399999999999 -1.46802203110511,53.38399869049681,3
</coordinates>
</LinearRing>
</outerBoundaryIs>
</Polygon>
</MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
</Document>
</kml>
```

According to the coordinates, we can get the normal of them (by cross product), 1.27245E-10,-0.000460805,-1.17167E-15 and 7.40792E-11,-0.000268555,-6.81175E-16 , then dot product them, get 1.23752E-07 > 0. But the kml was rendered as one is darker than the other one.

Is there something wrong with my kml file? or is this really an issue of google earth?

Any reply will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the winding so the coordinates are in the other directions.

Comment: Yes, actually I knew changing the winding may make it work, but according to the current coordinates and calculation, the orientation should be correct, the coordinates order of the two polygon are the same, but they were shown different in google earth. So I suspect this would be an bug of google earth.